# C++ GDI+ Objects Memory leak/too many objects?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gdi+

ive been making a c++ drawing program and i have a part where im drawing using gdi+ inside a function so i need to declare my graphics object every time i call the function.. this obviously is wrong and causes a leak somewhere so after some calls it gets slower and then suddenly stops drawing all together ,as expected.

im trying to clear my objects every time it finishes drawing but it doesnt seem to solve the issue. i thought maybe the PEN objects are part of the issue but some insight would be very helpful
my code:

```
void function()
{
    DWORD pdwGduStartup;
    GdiplusStartupInput GdiStartupInp;
    GdiplusStartup(&pdwGduStartup, &GdiStartupInp, NULL);
    Pen pnPen_Blue(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 255), 2.0F);
    Pen pnPen_Green(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 255), 2.0F);


    LPCSTR LGameWindow = "MyWindow";
    HWND hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, LGameWindow);
    Graphics graphics(GetDC(hGameWindow));
for (int n=10; n>0; n--)
    graphics.DrawLine(&pnPen_Green,0, 0, 0, n);
    GdiplusShutdown(pdwGduStartup);
    graphics.Flush();
}
```

thanks alot!

edit: added release DC did not do anything!

```
DWORD pdwGduStartup;
GdiplusStartupInput GdiStartupInp;
GdiplusStartup(&pdwGduStartup, &GdiStartupInp, NULL);
Pen pnPen_Blue(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 255), 2.0F);
Pen pnPen_Green(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 255), 2.0F);


LPCSTR LGameWindow = "MyWindow";
HWND hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, LGameWindow);
HDC GDC = GetDC(hGameWindow);
Graphics graphics(GDC);
ReleaseDC(hGameWindow, GDC);
GdiplusShutdown(pdwGduStartup);
graphics.Flush();
```

My GDI objects still rises up to 10,000!

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think the Pen class destructor should delete any internal GDI objects it uses.

Comment: @jensa, but how could i destroy it? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor

Comment: You never call an objects destructor explicitly, the language does that for you when the object goes out of scope. In this particular case, when the function ends.

Comment: Just because you call ReleaseDC does not mean you are cleaning up GDI objects.

Comment: then how do i do it?

Comment: how do you use pnPen_Blue and pnPen_Green?

Answer (score 3):

GdiplusShutdown must be called after all GDI+ objects are removed. In your code Pen and Graphics destructors are called after GdiplusShutdown, when the objects go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx). You should call [ReleaseDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162920(v=vs.85).aspx) or use WTL smart pointers.

As I remember such things where easy to debug with task manager. It shows HANDLE count as well as GDI object count for a process, so you can see what lines generate new objects.

Comment: it gets up to 10,000 objects and stops working.. i cant seem to be able to release DC

Comment: 10,000 objects is a limit after which it stops working. You should try to debug your code and keep track of when new gdi objects are created. You can view the GDI object count in Task Manager (Select columns -> GDI objects) or Process Explorer.

Comment: You can try to comment the entire code and test it uncommenting line by line.

Comment: to find what? i dont know what usually removes the objects

Comment: First of all to ensure that the leak is inside your function. Try to leave only GdiPlus startup/shutdown functions. Then add find window. Then line drawing.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt code my GDI+ right logically. in the logic first you need to create the graphics object, and only then loop draw on it. anything else is WRONG and code wont fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, use pointers that you can easily delete when done.

```
DWORD pdwGduStartup;
GdiplusStartupInput GdiStartupInp;
GdiplusStartup(&pdwGduStartup, &GdiStartupInp, NULL);
Pen pnPen_Blue* = new Pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 255), 2.0F);
Pen pnPen_Green* = new Pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 255), 2.0F);

LPCSTR LGameWindow = "MyWindow";
HWND hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, LGameWindow);
HDC GDC = GetDC(hGameWindow);
Graphics* g = new Graphics(GDC);

// Do stuff here

ReleaseDC(hGameWindow, GDC);
delete pnPen_Blue;
delete pnPen_Green;
g->Flush();
delete g;
delete GDC; // not sure
GdiplusShutdown(pdwGduStartup);
```